# How to copy SQL column data to new column then drop the original column?

Tags: sql, type-conversion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am following the recommendation in this [sql snowflake forum](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009NCWYtSAP/in-snowflake-can-we-change-a-data-type-from-number380-to-varchar512-if-yes-then-how-because-i-am-trying-to-do-this-but-not-reaching-at-any-point) in order to transform an integer data column into a varchar by creating a new column. I want to drop the original integer column when I am done, but doing so always results in the new column no longer working and any future queries erroring out.

For instance, I have `test_num` is the integer and `test_num_to_char` is the varchar

```
alter table test_table 
    add test_num_to_char varchar as CAST(test_num as varchar)
```

then

```
alter table test_table 
    drop column test_num

select * 
from test_table
```

results in an error message:

> SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300002:224117369

Is there a different transformation method that removes the dependency on the original integer column so I can drop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alter table test_table add test_num_to_char varchar(10);
go

update test_table set test_num_to_char = CAST(recno as varchar);
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom! That's exactly what I did, but then when I drop the integer column it's casting from, the new varchar column no longer works. Any ideas?

Comment: Not quite. This method creates a new column with data in it. Your method creates a computed column.

Comment: Ah I see! Actually, you're right that did it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try the TO_DECIMAL transformation method.

It's documentation is given [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_decimal.html)

Comment: Thanks, Yash! But I think that is the opposite of what I'm trying to do. It looks like that converts from varchar or integer to a fixed point number. I am trying to convert from integer to varchar and have that preserved after I drop the original integer column. PS: I tried the TO_VARCHAR function, which is the equivalent of TO_DECIMAL, and get the same error message listed in the main question after I drop the integer column it's based on.

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake.

Comment: No problem, please let me know if you have any other ideas!